# About Firefox vs. Chrome print to pdf tool when using @media print

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) at-rule can specify a media query, such as `print`, to apply css rules to the document.

Let's say I have the following code:

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 3in;
    margin: 0.2in;
  }
}

body {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Title for the page</h1>
  <p>Some text goes into here.</p>
</body>
```

When I open this `html` webpage in Chrome, with its "Print to pdf" tool, I get a satisfactory result - the user can't change the exported pdf size, it is determined by the css rule, 3inch×3inch in this case. However, you can change the margins in this GUI, although I explicitly set it in the second rule.

**EDIT:**
When choosing "Default" margins in the printing tool, the margins indeed follow the rule set up in the css file.

On the other hand, on Firefox, the user can simply change the pdf page size, change the orientation and how to scale the content into the page. If so, then what effect does the css rule have?

So my question is mainly towards Firefox behavior: Is that a bug or rather is it ok?

Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Comment: I think it's just how the browsers work, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN, `@page/size` CSS rule is simply not supported in Gecko and WebKit based browsers (Firefox and Safari) as of 2021-10.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size#browser_compatibility

[image: Compatibility table from linked page showing no support in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari]

Bugzilla entry: [[css3-page] implement @page rule size attribute](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851441)

Comment: That solves the confusion.